# How to clean up current oracle user's privilege

Tags: oracle, database-administration

It has been report that current Oracle 11g schema user has privilege out of the limit, for example, user has full import/export privilege on whole database, user can do DDL on other schemas.

So how can we find out current user's privilege and clean it up using query? I know there are three

```
SELECT * FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS; 
SELECT GRANTEE, TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGE FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS WHERE GRANTOR='USERNAME';
SELECT * FROM USER_ROLE_PRIVS;
```

But which one is the most wanted and how to clean up? Seems currently neither one gives full privilege of current user that produce the issue.

Comment: Your queries should cover everything; grants are either for an object or a system privilege, and and are either direct or to a role.  A "bad" privilege could be in any of the three queries.  I'm not sure if we can help you, there are no evil grants, it depends entirely on your system.

Comment: @jonearles Thanks. So can I use one of above queries to check whether current user have privilege to impdp or expdp oracle database? The user does has this privilege, but not shown in either of the query result.

Comment: Yes.  In addition to Dave's answer, I would think the old roles for regular IMP and EXP, IMP_FULL_DATABASE and EXP_FULL_DATABASE, would be just as dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most dangerous privileges are the ones with ANY in their names -- SELECT ANY TABLE, ALTER ANY VIEW etc.. They should be strictly for DBAs and support staff only.

The roles you're looking for are DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE and DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE I believe.

Comment: Thanks, I am a newbie on Oracle so can I ask what is the query to find the list of schemas current user can access?